# Any cloud framework with a PHP/REST API?

Tags: cloud, cloud-hosting

I'm actually considering starting to offer my own cloud service and i was wondering if anyone knew a cloud infrastructure management software which is actually 'free' and 'production ready'.

My requirements are :

- Open source (free)
- Management GUI (with billing and user/role based management)
- Use 'cheap' file backends such as NFS or iSCI
- Built-in backup/restore access for the client
- Manage xensource or xenserver or kvm nodes
- Has an API (better if PHP or HTTP based)
- "easy" to understand and implement (must be set up and running in less than a day)

I know about :

- OpenStack (good, but no GUI)
- SolusVM (very good, but lack of modularity, closed source)
- Archipel (looks veeery promising, but still not released)

Any other projects i may missed out ?

Comment: What's your definition of "production ready"? That phrase really only means anything if you're in the marketing department of some company...

Comment: +1 ErikA. Could almost add that question for every term used in the question; "good", "cloud", "framework", "easy"... etc.

Comment: Oh, and the old adage most certainly applies here: Fast, Cheap, Stable - pick two.

Comment: Sorry for my non-technical english; what I meant by "production ready" was a framework that has been efectively implemented an known to work; from what i've seen there are numerous attempts but nothing really worth putting live clients and rely on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd highly doubt there exists (or will ever exist) an all-in-one solution that fits your requirements. To be perfectly honest, if you need to ask these types of questions, chances are good that you ought not to be even attempting to get into this business.

Without exception, every "cloud service" (whatever that means) that I know of has very large library of custom code that they use to manage their environment. You're going to have a rough go of it if you're unable or unwilling to write custom code for your proposed venture.

Comment: I would say this isn't only true for fog services, but for every net based service, be it an ISP, a mail provider, domain registrar, web hoster, rackspace provider, whatever.

Comment: @SvenW - agreed 100%.

Comment: willing to write code, but the less possible.